# How to create a Communications Type page in SharePoint Team Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-team-site

I was wondering if it was possible to recreate the "Topic" style page we get from a Communications Site in a Team Site.  I can create a Modern Page in the team site but I would like to have the Search and Quick Launch menu removed and have the full width of the screen, like the default Communication site page.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Client Side webpart with SPFX and use that to remove the Quick Launch and the Search bar with css or script on a modern page.

If you want to remove them on regular pages you can add a CustomAction that loads your javascript or css that makes the necessary changes with css or script.

Comment: Hi Magnus,  Thanks for your reply.  Is this the kind of modification that could have a problem with any updates from Microsoft?  Is that something that I'll just have to deal with should it arise?

Comment: @JohnCondron Yes but the ids you are targeting will not likley change. Please mark as answer if it helps you.

Comment: That's great Magnus, thank you very much for your help.